# Array store reference variable not working - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, reference

I'm a new guy in JavaScript, so diving in an new things make me get many problem...

In this case I want to store an array of reference variable , but it **not work**.

```
    var pressTimer, timers = [];
    function addEventTapHold(element, func, time) {
        document.getElementById(element).addEventListener('touchend', function(){
            console.log("Clear allll");
            //TRY TO CLEAR TIMEOUT OF ARRAY BUT NOT WORK
            for (var timer in timers) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
            }
            timers = [];

            //IMPLEMENT CODE


            return;
        });

        document.getElementById(element).addEventListener('touchstart', function(event){
            pressTimer = setTimeout(function(){
                func(element);
                isTapHold = true;
            },time);

            //PUSH TIMER TO ARRAY 
            timers.push(pressTimer);
        });
    }
```

I'm looking forward to hear some advise soon.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Side note: don't use a `for..in` loop to iterate over an array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description

Comment: Not: "pressTimer = setTimeout(" , But , it is : "var pressTimer = setTimeout("

Comment: [Learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging).

Comment: @FelixKling: I tried to debug, and array store reference varialbe properly, but when I use it to clearTimeout, it still not working.

Comment: @MattBall: I just want to clearTimeout all of timer, so I think It's ok if the order of element in array not properly. By the way I used "regular" for statement and problem still happens.
Could you have another suggestions ?

Comment: What does "not work" mean in this context? That's not a useful problem description.

Comment: so you will have alot of timers?

Comment: @jhyap Yes, so I want to manage it by an array and clearTimeout all of them when "touchend".

Comment: @FelixKling: I setTimeout to launch func() and if "touchend" happens earlier than timeout. i want to clear all timers. In this case I can see array store ref var, but I can not clearTimeout (func() still launch). Sorry about my bad description.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your function is expecting the argument "time", not "timers"

Comment: Oh sorry, it's my mistake. It should be more clear, "timers" is declared out of function, "time" is passed variable to set timeout. I edited the description.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var timers = [];
    function addEventTapHold(element, func, time) {
        document.getElementById(element).addEventListener('touchend', function(){
            console.log("Clear allll");
            //TRY TO CLEAR TIMEOUT OF ARRAY BUT NOT WORK
            for (var timer in timers) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
            }
            timers = [];

        //IMPLEMENT CODE


        return;
    });


    document.getElementById(element).addEventListener('touchstart', function(event){

         //define the pressTimer as local variable here 
         var pressTimer = setTimeout(function(){
            func(element);
            isTapHold = true;
        },time);

        //PUSH TIMER TO ARRAY 
        timers.push(pressTimer);
    });
}
```